# :alert does not work; :notice does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For some reason my `:alert` does not work, whereas `:notice` works just fine.

```
<% if notice %>
    <p id="notice" ><%= notice %></p> 
<% elseif alert %>
    <p id="alert" ><%= alert %></p> 
<% end %>
<%= yield %>
```

Anyone know why `:alert` is not working? I'm using **Rails 3.1.0.RC5**

**EDIT:** Found a more effective method thanks to **Reuben Mallaby** for display all notices and alerts.

```
<%- flash.each do |k, v| %>
    <div id="<%= k %>"><%= v %></div>
<% end %> 
<%= yield %>
```

Comment: elseif is elsif in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks dude! That pretty much fixed my issue :)

Comment: Yes, it's the same for Rails. Note that if you have both a notice and an alert, only the notice is shown. If you want both to be shown you'll have to use two seperate `if`/`end`s.

Answer (score 6):

To make sure you display all flash messages:

```
<%- flash.each do |k, v| %>
  <div id="<%= k %>"><%= v %></div>
```

Comment: Can you take a look at my edited version to see if it's correct?

Comment: Btw this work work for all notices and alerts right? So it would display the notice from the following code as well? `redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Password has been reset!"`

Comment: It should work for all flash messages - even custom ones like redirect_to root_path, :flash => { :cool=> "Rails rocks!" }

Answer (score 2):

Are these for flash? If so, do they work when explicitly calling flash?

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
    <p id="notice" ><%= flash[:notice] %></p> 
<% elsif flash[:alert] %>
    <p id="alert" ><%= flash[:alert] %></p> 
<% end %>
<%= yield %>
```

If not, it could be an issue in your controller. Please post the code that is setting the :notice and :alerts.

Comment: Thanks !The flash[:notice] is working but I need to implement an `elseif` method to get this to work with the alerts as well. Why is `elseif` throwing up `undefined method` error? Weird!

Comment: There is no elseif, it's a subtly different elsif. It's so subtle I missed it in your original question. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yeah I saw it in a comment to my original post. Thanks though =)